# MultiScaleImageSource GetTileLayers Explanation

Tags: wcf, silverlight, multiscaleimage

I have been doing reading on MultiScaleImage source, and finding anything useful has proven to be quite difficult, thus I turn to the experts here. The specific knowledge I would like to have pertains to the GetTileLayers method. I know this method is used to get the image tiles. But I have no idea where this method is called from, or where the parameters come from or how I would use it if I subclassed the MultiScaleTileSource Class. Any insight into this method or the MSI model would be amazing but I have 3 main questions:

**1. Where should/is the method GetTileLayers called from?

2. How should I change this method if I wanted to draw png's from a non-local URI?

3. Where can I find some reading to help with this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a custom tile source, you would subclass [`MultiScaleTileSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.multiscaletilesource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and override the `GetTileLayers` method, as shown in the example below, which defines an image consisting of 1000*1000 tiles of size 256x256 pixels each.

```
public class MyTileSource : MultiScaleTileSource
{
    public MyTileSource()
        : base(1000 * 256, 1000 * 256, 256, 256, 0)
    {
    }

    protected override void GetTileLayers(
        int tileLevel, int tilePositionX, int tilePositionY,
        IList<object> tileImageLayerSources)
    {
        // create an appropriate URI for tileLevel, tilePositionX and tilePositionY
        // and add it to the tileImageLayerSources collection

        var uri = new Uri(...);
        tileImageLayerSources.Add(uri);
    }
}
```

Now you would assign an instance of your MyTileSource class to your MultiScaleImage control:

```
MultiScaleImage msImage = ...
msImage.Source = new MyTileSource();
```

Comment: Thanks! After I have done that, where would I call the GetTileLayers method from? Does it magically get called from the background, or should I be handling it myself?

Comment: The MultiScaleImage control calls it when it needs to get the URI of a specific tile. That's why you have to override (implement) it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was working on an already developed app and I could not for the life of me find where that call was being made!